# Is it possible to set UIEdgeInsets on a NMAMapView?

Tags: ios, here-api

I've got some content to display over the top of an `NMAMapView`. I'd like to zoom and pan to specific bounding boxes, but I want it to respect a kind of edge inset, so that my overlaid content does not obscure what I want visible in the map view.

I've looked [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html), but can't find anything that might help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered it's possible to set a 'view frame' on an NMAMapView, using this function: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapView(im)setBoundingBox:insideRect:withAnimation:

I can't work out how to inset the content when using the navigation manager however, which would be great.

Answer (score 0):

this is right usage of NMAMapView API for Starter SDK.

Starter SDK have no NMANavigationManager. It available in Premium SDK.
If you use Starter SDK, please clarify what case with 'navigation manager' do you mean.

For Premium SDK additionally to 'setBoundingBox:insideRect:withAnimation' available 'clipRect' property:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapView(py)clipRect